# how can i pull symbol info in alert in strategy in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

syminfo.basecurrency

I'm trying to pull as follows, but I can pull data with {{ticker}} but {{syminfo.basecurrency}} value is not coming.

```
{
    "Quantity":"0.05",
    "OrderType":"PYS",
    "BaseCurrency":{{syminfo.basecurrency}}
    "Symbol":"{{ticker}}",
    "Exchange":"{{exchange}}",
    "Price":"{{strategy.order.price}}",
    "Side":"{{strategy.order.comment}}"
}
```

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvVMd.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no placeholder as `{{syminfo.basecurrency}}`. You can find the list of available placeholders from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000531021-how-to-use-a-variable-value-in-alert/).

As a workaround, you can construct your alert message yourself using strings and then fire an alert with `alert()`.